# I got SparkContext Error initializing SparkContext on WebSphere application server

Tags: java, apache-spark, websphere

When my java application, which uses "spark-core_2.11-2.3.0" library, is running on WebSphere 9.0.0.x application server i got the following error:

"[24.02.20 09:55:06:769 MEZ] 00000100 SystemOut     O 2020-02-24 09:55:06 [ERROR] SparkContext Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.Exception: Could not find resource path for Web UI: org/apache/spark/ui/static
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createStaticHandler(JettyUtils.scala:197) ~[spark-core_2.11-2"

This is not an issue when the application runs on Tomcat server.
From what I found the problem is that WebSphere uses different class-loading compared to Tomcat but i didn't find any solution that will fix my problem.